# can't click on checkbox to uncheck it seem like it's hidden

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the checkbox is checked be default and can't click on it to uncheck. here is my code but it came back as error saying element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException.

```
String checkboxXPath =("//input[contains(@type='checkbox',@name='key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera_checkboxVal')]");
                        WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath(checkboxXPath));
                        elementToClick.click();
```

Website code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="uwp_inputCheckBox" 
    name="key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera_checkboxVal" 
    id="key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera" 
    value="true" dir="ltr" hierarchy="false" expand="true" 
    checkedval="true" uncheckedval="false" 
    onclick="checkboxChange('IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera')" 
    checked="checked">
```

whole code

[whole code http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1720/SIi6Xj.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1720/SIi6Xj.png)

Comment: by default it is hidden? is it depends on any condition? if not then you should just use explicit wait before click on it. As sometime it happens that element takes little time to load.

Comment: I'm not sure because that element is a checkbox that when check another element will appear under it. but when unchecked the other element attached to it will disappear. as you can see in the highlighted code it's checked now and i want to uncheck it.

Comment: is it part of an iframe? is it part of a different window?

Comment: it is location under the externalUI frame and i already point to that one. I tried to ran the code with else and if to see if it's hidden or enable. It returned enabled. Thats mean it is there but i couldn't click it. When i add the click function it came back as org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use explicit wait until element get visible. Please check update code here and use it:

```
String checkboxXPath =("//input[contains(@type='checkbox',@name='key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera_checkboxVal')]");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(checkboxXPath)));

WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath(checkboxXPath));
elementToClick.click();
```

Comment: return as `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[contains(@type='checkbox',@name='key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera_checkboxVal')]
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'`

Comment: ok it means your that element is not getting visible within 30 seconds , please try with 60 seconds.

Comment: It saying the same thing as above even for 60 second. I think the problem is it's not going to appear automatically. We would need to enable it.

Comment: is there an way to force click it with java executor?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions. I'm not sure why your XPath is so complex when you have an ID on the element you want to click. Try this...

```
driver.findElement(By.id("key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera"));
```

I'm kinda guessing that won't work. Looking at the HTML, I see the `SPAN` right above the element that you want to click and it has an `onclick` on it. I'm guessing that if you click that, it might trigger the click of the checkbox... so let's try that...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.uwp_checkBoxSpan.uwp_checkBoxChecked"));
```

You might need to check my spelling on the class names... I couldn't copy/paste since it's a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium works on Javascript I would suggest you to test the checkbox clicking thing manually by entering a Javvascript. Here are the step you need to follow:

1. Execute the test case manually up till where your script failed.
2. Goto browsers developer tools option->Console. Enter a javascript
   command document.getElementById('key_IT_CONFIG.ios.restriction.functionality.enable.camera').click()

If this works then there is no reason why your code shouldn't work.